# Operator norm equality problem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have been reading one article about inequalities, and this equality is stated,
$$||T\pm S||^{2}=||(T\pm S)^{*}(T\pm S)||$$ where $T,S\in B(H)$.
How should I go about proving this? I know that
$$||T\pm S||=\sup_{x\in H,||x||=1}||(T+S)x||=\sup_{x\in H,||x||=1}\sqrt{\langle (T+S)x,x\rangle}$$
Squaring both sides, doesnt look like it leads me to the solution...

Thank you so much for helping me with this!

Comment: Perhaps start with something simpler like showing that $\|A\|^2 = \|A^*A\|$?

Comment: By the way, the equality you tried to use only works when $T+S$ is normal. For non-normal elements it can fail, even in finite-dimension.

Answer (score 1):

In a Hilbert space $H$, the equality :
$$\|A\|^2 = \|A^*A\|$$
holds for any $A \in B(H)$. Just apply this to $A = T \pm S$.

This is because for $x \in H$, you have :
\begin{align*}
\|Ax\|^2 &= \langle Ax, Ax\rangle\\
&= \langle A^*Ax, x\rangle\\
&\leq \|A^*A\|\|x\|^2 \leq \|A^*A\| \leq \|A^*\|\|A\|.
\end{align*}
Now take the supremum on $x$ to get $\|A\|^2 \leq \|A^*A\| \leq \|A^*\|\|A\| = \|A\|^2$. This chain of inequalities is then an equality.